# Secret messages in the office

Tags: cipher

A colleague recently sent you the following puzzle in an email.

> *ejsy lomf pg vpsy vsm pm;u nr [iy pm ejrm oy od ery*

What should your reply be?  To make it more fun, reply in the same language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> s vpsy pg [somy

Which means:

> A coat of paint

The clue is:

> "what kind of coat can only be put on when it is wet"

The key is:

> The QWERTY keyboard has been shifted to the right by one key!

Comment: am I right in assuming that you understand the signficance of the "key"?

Comment: @Mew yes, apparently that would be a safe assumption (now :p)